# How to specify numeric width and precision when creating a dBase database?

Tags: c#, .net, oledb, shapefile, dbase

We need to be able to create a dBase database (.dbf file) containing numeric columns with specific width and precision. I seem to be able to set the precision but not the width. The following code shows my connection string and my command text.

```
using (OleDbConnection oConnection = new OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source = {0};Extended Properties=dBase 5.0", msPath)))
{

  ....

  oCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [Field] ([Id] Numeric (15, 3))";
  oCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This gives me a column `Id,20,3` in the file.

There must be a way to set the field width without resorting to editing the .dbf file manually? Has nobody else come across this before when creating shapefiles?

Comment: @Andrew Kalashnikov - No, we never resolved this issue. The consumer of our shape files loosened their requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No solution could be found, if anyone can come up with one I will change my accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft OLE DB Provider](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)

Use the following conection:

```
connectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb.1;Data Source=" + path + ";Collating Sequence=machine;";
```

and you query:

```
comm.CommandText = "Create table Test (FirstName Numeric(4,0),LastName Char(50) )"
```